# 401 error after upgrading okta-spring-boot-starter version in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, okta, java-17

I have my security configuration class as below,

```
EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@Configuration
@Profile({"cloud", "development", "release", "production"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @Profile({"cloud", "development", "release", "production"})
    public static class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/students", "/api/v1/students/*").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/v1/students/*").hasAnyRole("admin")
                        .requestMatchers(this.getWhiteList().toArray(new String[0])).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        
        http.cors();
        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);

        return http.build();
    }
```

I'm using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3. Below is build.gradle file

```
  ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.0.2'
        springCloudVersion = '2022.0.0-M3'
    }
    implementation ('com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:3.0.2')
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
```

After increasing the okta-spring-boot-starter version Apis start to throw 401 exception even with a valid token.

In the log files seeing the below error

```
New HTTP session created: <number>

Call stack: 

    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter$DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:171)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:76)
```

In my Controller

```
@Validated
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "auth")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public class StudentController {

@PutMapping("students/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> updateStudent(
```

Comment: can you capture request/responses sent out to Okta to inspect which one gives you 401 and what are the params of the req?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev All the APIs which are authenticated are throwing the 401 error. With/without parameters.

Comment: What version were you using before you upgraded? Can you please try version 3.0.3.

Comment: @MattRaible  Earlier I was using Java 11 with okta-spring-boot-starter 2.0.0. It was working with that version. But even with java 11, if I upgraded okta-spring-boot-starter to 2.1.6 it started to give the same error(Throwing 401 from all the  APIs even with a valid token).

Comment: I tried by upgrading the 3.0.3 and also by downgrading 3.0.0. Still the issue is persisting.